# Suddenly, I start from the root directory not my home directory when I login. I want to start from my home directory

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

From some point, suddenly (I guess after an Ubuntu update?), it starts in the root directory when I open a new terminal.
I want to start from my home directory as before.

The below is my shell script(I removed all the comments).
I am running Ubuntu on WSL2 on Windows 10

```
export ZSH="/home/myubuntu/.oh-my-zsh"
ZSH_THEME="bira"
DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

alias tre='tree -a -C -I '\''node_modules|.git'\'' --dirsfirst'

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion

#cd workspace
if [ "$PWD" = "$HOME" ]; then cd workspace; fi

# added by travis gem
[ ! -s /home/myubuntu/.travis/travis.sh ] || source /home/myubuntu/.travis/travis.sh
```

This is Ubuntu info

```
╰─$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Does your home directory exist?  If it doesn't (like if /home was not mounted), then the default current working directory is probably /

Comment: I don't have WSL2 up and running so I can't verify this but if you have access to your settings.json file, change the starting directory path to `/home/username` where username = your actual username. Example: `/home/taeil`

Comment: I found the answer [here](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/11812#issuecomment-977198964) and they reference another [similar answer that involves using a path with backslashes instead](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6995#issuecomment-934115519)

Comment: @ubfan1 it exists.

Comment: @mchid Thank you, that is the problem I have. WOW, you have much better googling skills than me, I couldn't find it by googling for hours.

Comment: @mchid Yap yap yap, I could fix it by replacing forward-slash to back-slash in settings.json

...
"startingDirectory": "\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\home\\taeil",
...

Comment: @mchid please post an answer explaining the solution so this question can be marked as answered.

Comment: I'm pretty sure WSL2 provides a command line to start Ubuntu as a certain user under the windows terminal, perhaps not so convenient as you have expected though.

Comment: @funicorn Actually, it's pretty convenient.  `wsl -u <username>` will start as any user that is defined in Ubuntu.  Also `wsl ~` will start in the home directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in the comments that you got this working, but there are several ways to do this under Windows Terminal:

- Under Windows 10 21H2 and Windows 11, you can specify a Linux directory instead of the Windows path for `startingDirectory`.  So now `/home/taeil` will work (assuming you are upgraded).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70135856/11810933) on Stack Overflow for details and a link to the Microsoft Doc.
- Under previous versions, you do need to use the *Windows* format `\\wsl$\` path (quoted) as noted in the comments.  In your case, it looks like this would be `\\\\wsl$\\Ubuntu\\home\\taeil`
- Personally, for using your Linux *home* directory as a starting point, I recommend [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70136022/11810933) (my answer in that same Stack Overflow question).  Just start wsl with `wsl ~` to start in your home directory.
- Also, with Windows 10 21H2 and Windows 11, `wsl --cd ~` works.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed following the comment. but still good to know various ways.
startingDirectory: "~" seems the best way to me.

Comment: @Taeil Ah, if only it worked.  I just tried it, and it doesn't :-/.  I would have thought that it would pass the `startDirectory` to the `wsl --cd` command, but apparently not.  I usually just edit the `commandLine` property myself and force it to `wsl ~`, which I do know works, but if you want to use `startingDirectory':`/home/taeil` is probably the next best thing.